# bind gridview in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have list of manifests and the user can right click on an item from the list and that shows a dialog box. In this dialog box is a few textboxes and the GridView. 
The values for the textboxes are loaded from a function in JavaScript so I need to load the GridView in this function to:

```
 function EditManifest(ID) {
            PageMethods.GetManifestNew(ID, OnGetManifestNew, null);
        }

        function OnGetManifestNew(result) {
            if (result.ID != -1) {
                document.getElementById('txtEdtManifestID').value = result.ID;
              }
          }
```

I know if I was to load the GridView in the code behind it would be like this:

```
List<Manifest> costs = new List<Manifest>();
 gvCosts.DataSource = costs;
 gvCosts.DataBind();
 udpCosts.Update();
```

But how do I do something like this in JavaScript? 
Or can I call a function in the code behind from `OnGetManifestNew` so I use the bind code?

Comment: You can do it some different ways, but are they good solutions. If you develop asp.net webform, maybe you think "I have gridview, I can handle lots of things in the server side" after then, some problem appears and you try to solve it in client side. In my opinion, you should try to create all gridview in clientside. 

1.Get value from db or somewhere else on serverside,
2.Convert it to JSON object.
3.Send it to client side.
4.Then loop in object and create your own gridview(actually html table or divs). 

.. because this approach is better.

Comment: @KnowGe The GridView is being created in the clientside. I just want to be able load the GridView from the javascript function

Comment: how do you pass list of manifest to the client side before creating gridview ?